# What version of Raspberry Pi ( if at all ) is it?

Tags: raspbian

I have a Rasberry Pi with the 2011 stamp, but it's screwy compared to the ones I've found online so far...   Two USB connectors, HDMI, audio, ethernet, and RCA.  Fine so far.   Two of the risers.  SD slot, so far so good.

The story is that I worked with a company that did heavy cross-compilation and compiler work, and they gave it to me the first year with no explanation other than "rasberry pi".  It's so slow there's about a 10 second delay between clicks and responses, and even the keyboard isn't immune.  The forum has been helpful at sorting out some other speed issues.

*Should also note that I couldn't find a single model laid out like this online or elsewhere.  I know about 20 people with them but that's where the story ends.*

Thanks for whatever info you can give.  :-)

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS 697.95
Features swp half thumb fastmult cfp edsp java tls
CPU implementer 0x41
CPU Architecture 7 
CPU Variant 0x0
CPU Part 0xb76
CPU Revision 7

Hardware BCM2708
Revision 2
Serial 000000005d643198
64MB Ram / 16MB VRam.   Never seen one before, any ideas?
```

[image: Front]

[image: Back]

Comment: And your question is??

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear.  I was wondering if anyone had seen this particular board before and only wanted to see if anyone else had seen one.   Nobody I talked to could ID it and google images doesn't have it.   Just wondering about manufacture and rarity.

If anyone is interested I can post chip numbers and such, but I have the feeling this one was lost in time.

Comment: That is obviously an Raspberry Pi Model B (not B+) and not Pi 2 Model B or Pi 3 Model B. I've got 2 of them and a broken one.
https://nicegear.co.nz/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-model-b/

Comment: I have two model B's, one with a black 3.5mm jack like the above and one with a pale blue one.  I believe the black ones were used on the made in China boards, the blue on the made in the UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the early Pi models. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/revision-codes/README.md

Updated link https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#new-style-revision-codes

This should still work, and can even use the latest Raspbian OS.

I probably have one in my junk box.

Comment: It sat in my junk box for 7 years.   I'm running mine with everything seemingly working, couldn't find anybody I know to ID the board so thanks.  

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It's one of the first Raspberry Pi Model B (revision 0002)

https://elinux.org/RPi_HardwareHistory

```
Revision Release Date   Model       PCB Revision  Memory  Notes
Beta     Q1 2012        B (Beta)    ?             256 MB  Beta Board
0002     Q1 2012        B           1.0           256 MB    
0003     Q3 2012        B (ECN0001) 1.0           256 MB  Fuses mod and D14 removed
```

Here's mine:

[image: Front view of revision 0002 Raspberry Pi Model B]

[image: Rear view of revision 0002 Raspberry Pi Model B]